# Page view in Container not showing content

Tags: ios, swift2, uipageviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am trying to place a page view onto the main view with a container. I followed a video to make a test page view as I am new to swift. I made it work in the test and then copied over most of the code and changed the relevant variables. When I run the app, the container shows up with no content.

This is my page content view controller.

```
class TodayPicksViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var todayShirt: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var todayPants: UIImageView!

var pageIndex: Int!
var shirtName: String = ""
var pantsName: String = ""



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.todayShirt.image = UIImage(named: self.shirtName)
    self.todayPants.image = UIImage(named: self.pantsName)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

This is my main view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var shirtImages: NSArray!
var pantsImages: NSArray!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.shirtImages = NSArray(objects: "shirt1", "shirt2")
    self.pantsImages = NSArray(objects: "pants1", "pants2")

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as TodayPicksViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers((viewControllers as! [UIViewController]), direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
   // self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TodayPicksViewController {
    if ((self.shirtImages.count == 0) || index >= self.shirtImages.count){
        return TodayPicksViewController()
    }

    let vc: TodayPicksViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! TodayPicksViewController
    vc.pantsName = self.pantsImages[index] as! String
    vc.shirtName = self.shirtImages[index] as! String
    vc.pageIndex = index


    return vc

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! TodayPicksViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if ((index == 0 ) || index == NSNotFound){
        return nil
    }

    index -= 1

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc = viewController as! TodayPicksViewController
    var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

    if (index == NSNotFound){
        return nil
    }
    index += 1

    if (index == self.shirtImages.count){
        return nil
    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return self.shirtImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

I have played around with changes hopefully getting something to work and the closest I was able to get returned the error message `CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:`

I looked up the error message and it suggested that I may be passing a nil value to the image view but as far as I can tell, they are set up exactly the same as the test project I made. Maybe it has something to do with parent/child relationships but I am not sure. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is commented when it should not be:

```
// self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
```

With this commented, you're never actually adding the `UIPageViewController` to the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry that commented line was left that way before I posted the question unintentionally while I was making some changes. Even with that line not commented, I still have the error.

Comment: I asked a more relevant  and updated question about the same issue here if you don't mind taking a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36560473/uiimage-name-from-array-keeps-returning-nil-value?noredirect=1#comment60721633_36560473

Comment: What error? That nothing appears on screen or that your images give an error? Cause I saw your other question about the images, and the problem was that you were initialising your variables too late.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on that a bit? Sorry I'm new to this, just trying to get some clarity. Where should I initialize them?

Comment: I commented on your other question.