# UIImage name from array keeps returning nil value.

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift2, uipageviewcontroller

Setting up a page view inside of a container. Followed all instructions I could find (beginner).

These two arrays are in the main view controller which have names of the images I want to populate the pages.

```
self.shirtImage = NSArray(objects: "shirt1", "shirt2")
self.pantsImage = NSArray(objects: "pants1", "pants2")
```

Whenever I run the program, these two lines:

```
self.todayShirt.image = UIImage(named: self.shirtName)
self.todayPants.image = UIImage(named: self.pantsName)
```

return the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` or `CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:` which means somehow they are receiving a nil value from the arrays.

The page content class looks like this:

```
class TodayPicksViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var todayShirt: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var todayPants: UIImageView!

var pageIndex: Int!
var shirtName: String!
var pantsName: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.todayShirt.image = UIImage(named: self.shirtName)
    self.todayPants.image = UIImage(named: self.pantsName)
```

and the main view controller is set up like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
var shirtImage: NSArray!
var pantsImage: NSArray!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.shirtImage = NSArray(objects: "shirt1", "shirt2")
    self.pantsImage = NSArray(objects: "pants1", "pants2")

    self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as TodayPicksViewController
    let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers((viewControllers as! [UIViewController]), direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)


    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 60)

    self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TodayPicksViewController {
    if ((self.shirtImage.count == 0) || index >= self.shirtImage.count){
        return TodayPicksViewController()
    }

    let vc: TodayPicksViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TodayPicksViewController") as! TodayPicksViewController
    vc.shirtName = self.shirtImage[index] as! String
    vc.pantsName = self.pantsImage[index] as! String
    vc.pageIndex = index


    return vc
}
```

I have another project that has a working page view similar to this and everything works perfectly and I have copied over almost everything exactly so I cannot figure out why the value from the main view controller is not properly passing to the page view in this one. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure I follow. How should I have done that?

Comment: @andrewxt I think you either have an issue where you are setting the image to the UIImageView (i.e. the syntax for setting the image is wrong) or you have an issue in your image naming (you may not have all of the images named correctly). I answered this down below, just follow what I said to do! It should help, let me know if it does not.

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you mean this to be in the main view controller or in the page content view controller?

Comment: I think you might be making that array in a subpar way. That's my next idea :). Check out my revised solution below. Basically, you're removing all your NSArray stuff and creating two new NSMutableArrays outside the viewdidload().

Answer (score 0):

Something is going wrong when you change the image of the UIImageView. Try `todayShirt.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "\(shirtName)")` and `todayPants.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "\(pantsName)")`.

Then **be very very sure** that you have 4 images inserted in your XCode project: `shirt1.png`, `shirt2.png`, `pants1.png`, and `pants2.png`. It's also ok if they are `shirt1.jpg`, etc.

If this still isn't helping, try changing your array-creation method. Instead of using NSArray and only adding objects to it in the `viewdidload()` section, just create the arrays & add objects in the global scope. So, right now where you have `var shirtImage: NSArray` and `var shirtImage: NSArray`, remove both of those and add `var shirtsArray:NSMutableArray = ["shirt1", "shirt2"]` and `var pantsArray:NSMutableArray = ["pants1", "pants2"]`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have the correct assets in the project. Also when I try the imageLiteral line, Xcode insists I add endless commas to the end of it. Not sure if it is a IDE bug or another issue.

Comment: @andrewxt try it again, I made a mistake with the quotation mark/parenthesis placement.

Comment: I got an error at the same line unfortunately. This time, however, I didn't get an error message at all. According to the error breakpoint, `shirtName` and `pantsName` still appear to be nil

Comment: @andrewxt try not creating your image NSArrays in the `viewdidload()` section. It might fix your error to assign the images to the array up top, or else use a different type of array (try NSMutableArray).

Comment: do you mean for this to move from the main view controller to the page content view controller? I tried it in the main one and still returned a nil value. If it helps, I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ) video for much of this. The page view is also in a container if it makes a difference.

Comment: @andrewxt No I mean to replace your NSArrays with NSMutableArrays, and add the content to the arrays outside of view did load (at the global scope, so they initialize with the values) preventing risk of your error, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found your problem, is your code entering in this if-statement?

```
if ((self.shirtImage.count == 0) || index >= self.shirtImage.count){
    return TodayPicksViewController()
}
```

If so, `shirtName` and `pantsName` will never have been initialised.

Comment: I thought that I had given them values in the  `viewControllerAtIndex` method of the main view controller. Do I need to give them values in another location?

Comment: You're right, but I think I found the problem now, I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried commenting out that if statement to see if it would return vc instead but I got the same error. Im not sure if it makes a difference, but page view is within a container. If it means anything, the bulk of this code came from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ).